# Floating one text to left, other to right

Tags: html, css, text, css-float

I am trying to float one `p` tag to the left, another `p` tag to the right. They share the same div as parent. I am unable to achieve this. The right text is positioned correctly horizontally, but vertically it is underneath the left text. Here is the code:

```
<div>
    <p id="t1">Text1</p>
    <p id="t2">Text2</p>
</div>

div {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#t1 {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: inline;
}
#t2 {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}
```

This is the result I have been getting: http://jsfiddle.net/JJB2s/ Now if I try to float the t1 text to left, they are both at the same vertical level, but they seem to be much lower than they should be. I am not quite sure why this happens and how to fix it, can somebody explain it to me please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: here is an update to your fiddle .. http://jsfiddle.net/JJB2s/12/

Comment: Just remove display:inline from both div's css and add float:left or Float:right in #t1.you will get the right behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement this using floats. Right now you don't have both of them floating, and are trying to use inline display to get them to line up. Here's an updated fiddle that fixes this:

http://jsfiddle.net/JJB2s/13/

The CSS is reproduced below:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#t1 {
    border: 1px solid green;
    float: left;
}

#t2 {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: right;
}
```

Note that putting `overflow: hidden` on the container keeps it from collapsing since it contains floats. This same effect could be achieved using the [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) if you don't actually want the overflow to be hidden

Comment: Nice! Why is it that it actually floats them with such a big margin? Why are they not touching the top of the div?

Comment: It's because paragraph tags come with margins from the user agent stylesheet. You can reset these if you want as such: http://jsfiddle.net/JJB2s/14/

Comment: What you're seeing is called *margin collapse*.  The non-floated elements have their margins collapsed (merged with the margins of a preceding element), but the floated elements don't.

Answer (score 0):

Add margin-top:0px; to the right

like this

```
#t2 {
border: 1px solid blue;
display: inline;
margin-top:0px;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick pretty well, however there is still 1-2 px difference between them. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

It does this because there are two paragraphs. By default HTML will show each paragraph in a new line..and yes, change this by setting margin-top: 0px;

Answer (score 0):

Set margin and padding to 0; http://jsfiddle.net/JJB2s/15/

```
div, #t1, #t2{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
div {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#t1 {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: inline;
    float:left;
}
#t2 {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked Jeff Escalante answer (I also upvoted it),
but here is another solution with the same effect.
it's just for the purpose of showing another approach.. use his answer.

Here is a [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/JJB2s/16/)

```
div {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
div:after
{
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
#t1 {
    border: 1px solid green;
    float: left;
}
#t2 {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: right;
}
```